# simple .htaccess 301 redirect multiple pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

So my **.htaccess** file looks like this

```
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 /page.html http://www.yoursite.com/newpage.html
Redirect 301 /page2.html http://www.yoursite.com/newpage.html
```

and it doesn't redirect my page.html

and if i leave it

```
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 / http://www.yoursite.com/newpage.html
```

it works, and redirect all my website. Now why is not working, and believe me, i have page.html near .htaccess file, and the frustation is that i have somthing like 10 .html to redirect, not more ... :(

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the equivalent result you can add this to your .haccess file before any other rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#redirect page or page2 .html
RewriteRule ^page(|2)\.html$ http://www.yoursite.com/newpage.html [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: ok,thanks, this work, but i don't want regex, just lines one under other like page2.html > newpath thepage1234.html > newpath